# Is it bad practice to import current file in python?

Tags: python

When I want to access variable from main.py in another .py file in same project I "import main as main".

In order to avoid having to use global keyword in my function in main.py  I also "import main as main" at top of main.py.

Is this bad practice?

main.py:

```
import main as main
status_line = 'Ready...'
root = ''


def test():
    print("Hello world")
    main.status_line.set('Hello world')
```

Comment: It definitely seems confusing.  If the goal is to just have that variable be available in two files, is there a reason that variable can't be in a third file?  Then main.py and another .py can both import from there?

Comment: Some quotes from The Zen of Python: "Explicit is better than implicit.", "Readability counts.", "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.", "If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea."

Comment: None of the reasons to avoid using global variables go away just because you've eliminated the `global` keyword. You've just obscured the fact that you are using a global.

Comment: @chepner Actually to me it seems clearer, as I have to ref each time I use it. Are there any official documents about this?

Comment: With `global`, there's only one thing `status_line` can refer to: the global name `status_line`. With `main.status_line`, you have to know if `main` is the local module, or some *other* object (module or otherwise) that has an attribute named `status_line`. You've just added *another* layer of indirection that doesn't provide any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

All you've done is obscured your use of the global variable `status_line`.

```
status_line = 'Ready...'
root = ''


def test():
    global status_line
    print("Hello world")
    status_line.set('Hello world')
```

(`str.set` doesn't exist, but the same arguments hold if you had just written `status_line = 'Hello world'` or `main.status_line = 'Hello world'`)

Here, at least it is clear(er) where `status_line` is defined. With your code, you've just introduced *another* global variable (albeit one that isn't modified) `main` whose purpose you need to know in order to understand what `test` actually does.

Answer (score -1):

Probably best not to do that. It may cause issues in terms of readability later for you and other programmers. 
Besides why would you want to call the import like that when you can just call it like a plain simple import to get the same result.